What are all of the different room modifiers in Cult of the Lamb?
In crusades during Cult of the Lamb, some rooms have little icons underneath them.
You can see one of them here in the top left below the sword:
What are all the modifiers in the game, and what do they do?

There can be some modifiers signified by the icon below the tab:






These are their meaning, respectively:

Chests drop Food ingredients not Coins
Chests drop double the Coins
Chests drop double the Coins + enemies drop poison pools
Enemies have half health + You receive double damage
Loses 1 max Heart, gain 1-3 Black Hearts
Loses 1 max Heart, gain 1 Tarot card

Source, Crusade page.
